# Symfony 2 search in hundred thousands rows

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, search, doctrine-orm

I search for my website developed under Symfony2, what questioned table database of hundreds of thousands of lines 2 columns.

Currently I use FULLIndex and like it, but it takes forever to respond, as this search engine is the very keystone of the site.

It therefore I need a strategy to implement, technical or network to optimize this search on this table and others as large and multiple columns.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you considerer use of external search engine like Apache Lucene (Solr) or Sphinx? Also please show us the exact database structure and queries that you're running.

Comment: Your description needs to include your efforts, more details about the data. Also share your thoughts on using a non-SQL DB or a specialized search index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a big database and you want to search data in it, I definitely recommend you ElasticSearch

There is a good bundle for this [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle).
This bundle is maintained by FOS. It's very easy to make it work in a symfony2 project

Comment: I try to configure it, but i have this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391173/configure-analysis-for-elasticsearch