# Configure analysis for ElasticSearch

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, yaml

i try configure ElasticSearch :

```
fos_elastica:
indexes:
    test:
        settings:
            index:
               analysis:
                   analyzer:
                       autocomplete:
                           type: custom
                           tokenizer: lowercase
                           filter   : [my_ngram]
               filter:
                   my_ngram:
                   type: "nGram"
                   min_gram: 2
                   max_gram: 20
        types:
            Track:
                mappings: 
                    title: { analyzer: autocomplete }
                    artist: { analyzer: autocomplete }
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model:  Website\TestBundle\Entity\Track
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
```

And this is my error when i do "http://mydomain.com:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=autocomplete&text=rih"

```
{"error":"ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [autocomplete]]","status":400}
```

What's the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says "failed to find analyzer [autocomplete]". In Elasticsearch you have several analyzers to your disposal by defaults. I am not aware of any autocomplete analyzer available by default, although you can create a custom analyzer and that could be the problem you're trying to solve.

If you're looking for autocomplete feel free to checkout the completion suggester documentation on the elasticsearch site or Sloan Ahrens tutorial on quick and dirty completion suggester
here:http://blog.qbox.io/quick-and-dirty-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-completion-suggest

If you're looking for more advanced techniques Sloan Ahrens has a great tutorial

here: http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams

I would provide all the documentation links to everything I am referencing but unfortunately I don't have the reputation points it takes to do so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and links ! But 'autocomplete' is just a name like 'toto' here, it's not for doing an autocomplete in particular, it's just the name of my custom analyzer... but it's dont find :s

Comment: Have you checked to see if the analyzer exists in your index settings?

Comment: I just configure it on the main config.yml of Symfony2. I need to configure it in an other file ?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to ask if you've checked your index settings "http://mydomain.com:9200/test/_settings" to make sure your custom analyzer exists?

Comment: Ok, this is the reply `{"test":{"settings":{"index.version.created":"901099","index.number_of_replicas":"1","index.uuid":"scRGbuLDSVicimrNv0g7vA","index.number_of_shards":"5"}}}` ... so i suppose is not exist ?

Comment: You're correct, it looks like you never put your index settings on your index.